# How to change set lock mode to wait in in spring boot application which use informix and jdbcTemplate?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, informix, jdbctemplate

I'm using Spring boot 2 with jdbcTemplate in my application. I used Informix.
I'm testing concurrency and I want my application to wait for a while when
a query try to update a row that is locked. This time can be set in informix
with 'SET LOCK MODE TO WAIT 20'. But I'm looking for a method in spring jdbcTemplate or something in spring.

I tried setting a timeout in the `jdbcTemplate.setQueryTimeout(60);` , but it did not work.

Any idea is welcome.

```
jdbcTemplate.setQueryTimeout(60);
cachedExecutor.execute(() -> jdbcTemplate.update(updatenIndoPeriodeInLfa()) );

cachedExecutor.execute(() -> jdbcTemplate.update(updatenAfroPeriodeInLfa()) );

private String updatenIndoPeriodeInLfa(){
        String query = "UPDATE  lfa " +
                "set indomonth = 09, indoyear = 2019 , indotype = indo " +
                "WHERE lfa.id in (select id " +
                "                   from   procindo " +
                "                   where  month   =   09    and" +
                "                          year    =   2019     and" +
                "                          type=   indo );";

        return query;
    }

    private String updatenAfroPeriodeInLfa(){
        String query = "UPDATE  lfa " +
                "set afromonth = 09, afroyear  = 2019 , afrotype = indo " +
                "WHERE lfa.id in (select id " +
                "                   from   procafro " +
                "                   where  month   =   09    and" +
                "                          year    =   2019     and" +
                "                          type=   afro );";

        return query;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think there is an abstraction of this in the `JdbcTemplate` or anywhere in Spring. 

The `JdbcTemplate` doesn't abstract over SQL.
And also it would be hard to abstract over this since I don't think an equivalent effect is possible in other databases.

Of course, the other question is: why don't you just execute that statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**After digging the Informix documentation I come across this:**

Application can use this property to override the default server process for accessing a locked row or table. Gets the value of the IFX_LOCK_MODE_WAIT variable, which is specific to Informix. The default value is 0 (do not wait for the lock). If the value has been set explicitly, it returns the set value. Returns: integer.
Sets the value of the IFX_LOCK_MODE_WAIT variable, which is specific to Informix. 
Possible values:

**-1** 
WAIT until the lock is released.

**0** 
DO NOT WAIT, end the operation, and return with error.

**nn** 
WAIT for nn seconds for the lock to be released.

**Then in my application datasource configuration, passed this property in as below:**

```
@Bean(name = "informixDataSource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver");

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("IFX_LOCK_MODE_WAIT", "60");

        dataSource.setConnectionProperties(properties);
        dataSource.setUrl(jdbc.getUrl());
        dataSource.setUsername(jdbc.getUser());
        dataSource.setPassword(jdbc.getPassword());

        return dataSource;
    }
```